# Fastest way to regroup every cell with the same value into a cellular noise

Tags: unity, c#, perlin-noise, heightmap

I'm working on a Map Generator, who are computed based on multiple height-map (I'm using FastNoise Asset on Unity Store to get all data) and they are split into Chunk.

Some noises are "cellular" and return the exact same value for group of cells next each others. Like:
[image: Cellular noise]

I want now be able to get all "zones" defined on a chunk, with all Coords who are into the zone, the center of the zone, ...
This is what I did so far, and it's working good, but it took in average **0.95sec to handle 240x240 cell !!** It's not something usable on runtime so I probably miss something.

```
float cellularHeight; // Current cell height
Dictionary<Coord, float> cellularHeights = new Dictionary<Coord, float>();  // Keep height for other cellular (to get if it's same than current)
Dictionary<Coord, int> cellularZoneIdx = new Dictionary<Coord, int>(); // Zone idx for every coord
Dictionary<int, List<Coord>> coordPerZoneIdx = new Dictionary<int, List<Coord>>(); // List of coord per zone idx
int nextZoneIdx = 0;
int countZone = 0;  // As zone can be merged, "next" is not a good way to get number of zone
int zoneIdxLeft = -1; // Someone at left ?
int zoneIdxBottom = -1; // Someone at bottom ? 

int idx = 0;
Coord cellCoord;
int countPerLine = 240;

for (int _y = 0; _y < countPerLine; _y++)
{
    for (int _x = 0; _x < countPerLine; _x++)
    {
        cellCoord = new Coord( _x, _y );

        // Get cellular value (stored in 1D float array)
        cellularHeight = this.heightmap[idx++];
        cellularHeights.Add(cellCoord, cellularHeight); 

        // Find if Left or Bottom cell are same ?
        zoneIdxLeft = zoneIdxBottom = -1;

        // Is the same than bottom ? (In all case (In left zone or not) we want this one to Bottom)
        if (_y > 0 && cellularHeights[cellCoord + new Coord(0, -1)] == cellularHeight)
        {
            zoneIdxBottom = cellularZoneIdx[cellCoord + new Coord(0, -1)];
            cellularZoneIdx.Add(cellCoord, zoneIdxBottom);
            coordPerZoneIdx[zoneIdxBottom].Add(cellCoord);
        }
        // Is the same than  left ?
        if (_x > 0 && cellularHeights[cellCoord + new Coord(-1, 0)] == cellularHeight)
        {
            zoneIdxLeft = cellularZoneIdx[cellCoord + new Coord(-1, 0)];

            // Current cell is on the same zone than left and bottom but both zone are not the same -> Regroup
            if (zoneIdxBottom != -1 && zoneIdxLeft != zoneIdxBottom)
            {
                foreach (Coord updateCellCoord in coordPerZoneIdx[zoneIdxLeft])
                {
                    cellularZoneIdx[updateCellCoord] = zoneIdxBottom;
                    coordPerZoneIdx[zoneIdxBottom].Add(updateCellCoord);
                }
                coordPerZoneIdx.Remove(zoneIdxLeft);
                countZone--;
            }
            else if (zoneIdxBottom == -1) // If not same Zone at bottom add to the left one (or it's already added to bottom)
            {
                // Add this to Left Zone
                cellularZoneIdx.Add(cellCoord, zoneIdxLeft);
                coordPerZoneIdx[zoneIdxLeft].Add(cellCoord);
            }
        }
        // No one
        if (zoneIdxLeft == -1 && zoneIdxBottom == -1) // New zone
        {
            cellularZoneIdx.Add(cellCoord, nextZoneIdx);
            coordPerZoneIdx[nextZoneIdx] = new List<Coord>();
            coordPerZoneIdx[nextZoneIdx].Add(cellCoord);

            nextZoneIdx++;
            countZone++;
        }
    }
}
```

Coord is a simple class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Coord {
    // Attributes
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }        
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + this.x + ";" + this.y + "]";
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Coord a, Coord b)
    {
        return (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Coord a, Coord b)
    {
        return (a.x != b.x || a.y != b.y);
    }
    // Dictionary.ContainKey
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Uniq string hashCode
        return (this.ToString()).GetHashCode();
    }
    // Dictionary.ContainKey
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Coord c = Coord.GetCoord(obj);
        return (c.x == this.x && c.y == this.y);
    }
    public static Coord operator +(Coord a, Coord b)
    {
        return new Coord(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }
    public static Coord operator -(Coord a, Coord b)
    {
        return new Coord(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
    }
}
```

How to do the same thing but way faster ?

Comment: have you tried using a breadth first search? this way you don't have to do the regroup logic.

Comment: Try sorting the cells and implement a binary search instead. Linear search is o(n2) while binary search is o(nlogn).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by zone & chunk. In the first image, it looks like you're generating a randomized Voronoi diagram. Are you trying to identify all the Voronoi cell 'centers' for a given rectangular region?

Comment: @Pikalek Chunk are square of 240x240 pixel (cell) returned by FastNoise, Every cell is a value between [0;1]. Zones are group of neighbours cells with same value.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin I'm not sure to understand, You propose that i'm need to sort cell coord by their heightmap value and than compute an array of sorted coord ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: (5/18/2019)**

If you are looking for how to get vertices (and other data like its range from 0 to 1, or its center point) of every cell generated in a Voronoi diagram, I would suggest using a Delaunay triangulation library. Coding this by hand is possible too, but may not be worth your time.

This one looks promising for Unity users: [csDelaunay](https://github.com/PouletFrit/csDelaunay)

[Here is a description and some example usage of this library.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/delaunay-voronoi-diagram-library-for-unity.248962/)

You can also use Lloyd's Relaxation in this library. Here is a demo showing this method: [demo](https://www.jasondavies.com/lloyd/)

This will require you some steps:

1. Get a list of polygon center points and each of their height values using the FastNoise heightmap.
2. Then you can go ahead and create your voronoi diagram using the above mentioned csDelaunay library.
3. If you want to detect each zone, simply loop through your polygon center points and check their corresponding height.
4. If you want to get the outline polygons of each zone (contiguous set of voronoi cells with same height ...like in Northgard), you will have to loop through the edges using a search function. To optimize this search, you could utilize recursion and/or sorting the data before searching.
5. If you want to be able to detect which zone a user has clicked on, you will have to loop through all the zones and check a point-to-polygon collision. To optimize this, you can use a quadtree and/or approximation methods for collision detection. In Unity, you might be able to register these zones as 2D collision hulls and just use the default collision check.

**ORIGINAL:**

The main line I noticed which may be causing slowdowns is:

`foreach (Coord updateCellCoord in coordPerZoneIdx[zoneIdxLeft])`

If you can avoid this, or optimize it, it will increase the speed by up to the average number of coords per zone. Maybe add a "checked" variable to each coordinate to avoid repetitions.

Another problem looks like the fact that you are looping through a 240x240 grid. Your focus could be on decreasing `countPerLine` and still get an acceptable result. You could convert your grid space into a smaller space (like in a Voronoi map) and then loop through those points instead of an entire grid.

This problem looks a little similar to Voronoi Diagrams. If you want to improve performance drastically, research the "Sweep Line" algorithm.

Also I would suggest putting conversion lines like:

`cellularHeight = this.heightmap[idx++];`

...into functions like:

`cellularHeight = this.getHeight(idx);`

...or something similar. This approach to your algorithms will help with avoiding small mistakes/repetitions with the index conversions in the long run.

Comment: Do you think that rendering 4 chunk of 120x120 ( or 16 or 60x60) will be way faster than 1 of 240x240 ? (And Thank for Voronoi Diagrams, didn't know about that)

Comment: Also, I tracked time using `Time.realtimeSinceStartup` to check what you say about the `foreach (Coord updateCellCoord in coordPerZoneIdx[zoneIdxLeft])` who may cause slowdowns and it return that the complete function took  0.80sec to compute and 0.0014 sec for the selected part of code. It's less than 1% of the total computing time.

Comment: That must mean the average number of coords per zone is little. What exactly are you trying to get and what is the input data?

Comment: I have a float[240x240] array of value between [0;1] and I want to list every group of coords (vonoroi cell ?), On my last try i had ~115 zones per chunk of 240x240 px

Comment: I see, so you want the list of vertices of every polygon generated by voronoi? Or do you only want the center point of each of those generated polygons?

Comment: I don't know that's the best way to handle zone like that, but i'm trying to achieve a render like on Northgard game terrain. Actually I'm trying to get a way to have functions who can return to me the current Zone for a requested Coord, and the list of Coords related to a Zone.

Comment: I updated my answer.